# Python Scikit-Learn: Custom Analyzer for TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

So i am trying to understand how to write a custom analyzer for python scikit-learn's TfidfVectorizer.

I am working on the following Kaggle competition

https://www.kaggle.com/c/whats-cooking

as a firs step, i do some clean up on the ingredients column as

```
traindf = pd.read_json('../../data/train.json')

traindf['ingredients_string'] = [' '.join([WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', line)) for line in lists]).strip() for lists in traindf['ingredients']]
```

after that i create a pipeline using TfidfVectorizer and the LogisticRegression classifier

```
pip = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(
                             stop_words='english',
                             sublinear_tf=True,
                             use_idf=bestParameters['vect__use_idf'],
                             max_df=bestParameters['vect__max_df'],
                             ngram_range=bestParameters['vect__ngram_range']
                             )),         

    ('clf', LogisticRegression(C=bestParameters['clf__C']))
    ])
```

then i fit my training set and finally, i predict

```
X, y = traindf['ingredients_string'], traindf['cuisine'].as_matrix()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7)

parameters = {}

grid_searchTS = GridSearchCV(pip,parameters,n_jobs=3, verbose=1, scoring='accuracy')
grid_searchTS.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = grid_searchTS.predict(X_test)
```

lastly, i check how my classifier did by

```
print ('Accuracy:', accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
print ('Confusion Matrix:', confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions))
print ('Classification Report:', classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```

now this gives me around 78% accuracy. fine. now i basically perform the same steps but with one change. instead of creating a new column in the dataframe for a cleaned up version of the ingredients, i want to create a custom analyzer that will do the same thing. so write

```
def customAnalyzer(text):

    lemTxt = ["".join([WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', ingred)) for ingred in lines.lower()]) for lines in sorted(text)]


    return " ".join(lemTxt).strip()
```

and of course i change the pipeline as

```
pip = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(
                             stop_words='english',
                             sublinear_tf=True,
                             use_idf=bestParameters['vect__use_idf'],
                             max_df=bestParameters['vect__max_df'],
                             ngram_range=bestParameters['vect__ngram_range'],
                             analyzer=customAnalyzer
                             )),         

    ('clf', LogisticRegression(C=bestParameters['clf__C']))
    ])
```

lastly, since i think my customAnalyzer will take care of everything, i create my train test split as

```
X, y = traindf['ingredients'], traindf['cuisine'].as_matrix()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7)
```

but to my surprise, my accuracy drops to 24% !

1. Is my intuition of using the custom analyzer in this way correct?
2. Do i also need to implement a custom tokenizer?

My intention is to use each ingredient as an independent entity. I do not want to deal with words. When i create my ngrams, i want the ngrams to be made out of each individual ingredient instead of each word.

How would i achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure your `customAnalyzer` logic is correct. Try combining its logic into one expression and test it on a sample `text` value to see if you're getting what you'd expect. For example:
`" ".join(["".join([WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', ingred)) for ingred in lines.lower()]) for lines in sorted('This is a sample sentence')]).strip()` yields `'t a a c e e e e h i i l m n n p s s s s t'`.